# Why is there a difference between the licensed Italian paper manga and scanlation of Bokura ga Ita?

Tags: manga-production, bokura-ga-ita

So I was reading the paper manga of *Bokura ga Ita* in my native language (Italian) and I noticed that some pages were really different from the scanlation, like there were some extra parts or some pages were missing.

For example, page 14 to 22 of chapter 67 in the scanlation has Yano visiting his old home and remembering his mother (a scene missing in the Italian version). Instead, in the Italian paper manga (as shown in the picture) has Yano discovering that Takeuchi left the engagement ring to him.

> [image: Italian page 14-15]
>
> <sup>(Italian manga book: chapter 67, pg. 14-15)</sup>

---

> [image: Scanlated page 15][image: Scanlated page 14]
>
> <sup>(Scanlation: chapter 67, pg. 14-15)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the cases where **the tankobon version revises the (flow of the) story of the original serialized magazine version**.

In this case, the scanlation is using the original serialized magazine version, where the Italian tankobon is based on the Japanese tankobon.

A [Japanese blogger](http://mirumo.serika.ciao.jp/?eid=909150) wrote a review for the last volume based on the original version and the tankobon version:

> 雑誌掲載時のものに加筆修正あり。
>
> There are additions & corrections to the serialized magazine version.
>
> 最終話もいろいろ描き足してありましたが
>   それ以外にも主に竹内くん関連で
>   セリフやモノローグがかわっていました。
>
> In addition to the many additional scenes in the last chapter, the speech and the monologue that are mainly related to Takeuchi were changed.
>
> 捨てたと思わせて実は持っていた指輪を
>   その指輪の意味がわかったら
>   捨てろという手紙とともに矢野の
>   ところにおいていった竹内君。[...]
>
> Takeuchi left the ring that was thought to be thrown away and a letter that says to throw away the ring if he understands the meaning of it at Yano's place. [...]

---

> 以下雑誌掲載時の感想
>   くらべてみると
>   最初１６巻を読んだときには
>   気づかなかったその違いに気づく・・。
>   かわっている部分が
>   より伝えたいことだったのだろうなと
>   改めてもう一度読み返しました。
>
> Below is my feeling when reading the serialized magazine version. When comparing to it, I noticed the difference that I hadn't noticed when reading volume 16 for the first time... the changed part meant more things to tell, thus I re-read it once again.
>
> 矢野は矢野で職場の草むしりのお手伝い。
>   バラの枝をみて母が育てていたバラを
>   思い出し、もと住んでいた場所にいってみると[...]
>
> Yano was helping to weed at his workplace. After seeing a rose bush, he remembered the roses that his mom raised, and went into their previous house [...]